# Azure STorage : Folder hierarchy under any container

Tags: c#, azure

I have created a Container named Content in azure using c#. I have uploaded files under this container as `"Images\myfile1.jpg","Images\myfile2.jpg","Images\myfile3.jpg"`

I want to get the list of all blobs that are uploaded in `Content container > Images folder`.

Is there any way to get that list?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get the list of all blobs that are uploaded in Content container > Images folder.

The [List Blobs operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs) can enumerate the list of blobs under the specified container, and you can make the results to return only blobs whose names begin with the specified prefix by specifying the `prefix` parameter on the URI.

**edit:**

If you'd like to using Microsoft Azure Storage Client Library for .NET, you can call [ListBlobs Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs?view=azurestorage-8.1.3) and specify the `prefix` parameter to filter the results.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={account_name};AccountKey={account_key};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net");

CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("Content");

List<IListBlobItem> blobslist = container.ListBlobs("Images", true).ToList();
```

Comment: using this `var query = container.ListBlobs(prefix: folderName, useFlatBlobListing: true, blobListingDetails: BlobListingDetails.None);`

Comment: If you are using Microsoft Azure Storage Client Library for .NET, [CloudBlobContainer.ListBlobs Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs?view=azurestorage-8.1.3) also accept ``prefix`` parameter.